# Ubuntu add bush script to autorun

Tags: bash, ubuntu

i have bash script "touchpad_settings.sh" :
`#!/bin/bash`
`### BEGIN INIT INFO`
`# Provides:          touchpad_settings.sh`
`# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog`
`# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog`
`# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5`
`# Default-Stop:      0 1 6`
`# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time`
`# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.`
`### END INIT INFO`
`ynclient TapButton2=2`
`synclient TapButton3=3`
`synclient VertEdgeScroll=1`
`synclient CircularScrolling=1`
and how can i make it to start with ubuntu and dont write
'sh /touchpad_settings.sh' in terminal every time when i turn on my laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create myscript.conf and save to /etc/init with content as below:

```
   author "Your name goes here - optional"
    description "What your daemon does shortly - optional"

    # When to start the service   
   start on runlevel [2345]

    # When to stop the service
    stop on runlevel [016]

    # Automatically restart process if crashed
    respawn

    # Specify working directory
    chdir path_to_your_script

    # run your script
    exec bash touchpad_settings.sh # or sh touchpad_settings.sh
```

After that type command to run your script.
`start myscript`

Your script now also run on machine startup.